# I have string base64 array in frontend. How can i send backend side this string array?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have string base64 array in frontend. I need to sent backend side this string array. I sent string array with ajax but the array's cells are null. How can I fix that problem?

Converting Image to Base64 code here:

```
var base64_string = [];    

var input = $(event.currentTarget);
var file = input[0].files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
   image_base64 = e.target.result;
   base64_string.push(images_base64);
}
```

My ajax code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var formdata = new FormData();

  $('#Ajax').click(function() {

    var ImageJsonText = JSON.stringify({
      base64_string: base64_string
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: 'main.aspx/ImageSave',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: ImageJsonText,
      traditional: true,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ImageSave(string[] base64_string) //request function with ajax
{



   return "OK!";
}
```

Comment: Where does base64_string come from?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. If you add this code to your .config document, It works. :)

```
<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
     <webServices>
       <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="999999999"/>
     </webServices>
   </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```